# Combo box not refreshed after insert/delete records

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am using vb.net and access 2007
I have a problem regarding combo box refresh

This is my code:

```
Private Sub comboRefresh()

    Try
        cmbSn_no.DataSource = Nothing
        cmbSn_no.Items.Clear()

        Dim asql As String = ("SELECT * FROM Vendor_det")
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(asql, cnnOLEDB)
        da.Fill(ds, "Vendor_det")

        cmbSn_no.ValueMember = "sr_no"
        cmbSn_no.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cmbSn_no.SelectedIndex = 0


        'DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        'DataGridView1.Update()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub cmbSn_no_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbSn_no.SelectedIndexChanged


    Dim asql As String = ("SELECT * FROM Vendor_det where sr_no='" & cmbSn_no.Text & "'")
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(asql, cnnOLEDB)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read = True Then

        cmbSn_no.Text = dr("sr_no")
        txtPart_no.Text = dr("part_no")
      .......... 
    End If
    cnnOLEDB.Close()
End Sub
```

And i call comborefresh() method from add and delete record button click events.
if i dont use the commented code and click on add / delete button then the output comes some how like this:

records in db:

abcd123
bbbc123

if i add a record cccc123.. it should update and my combo box should fill with following records:

abcd123
bbbc123
cccc123

but it fills with

abcd123
bbbc123
cccc123
abcd123
bbbc123

and if i use the commented line then the combo box is filled with "System.Data.DataRowView"
No prompted error comes but i am not getting my answer...
even i have tried with....

combobox.refresh()
combobox.selectedindex=-1
and 
combobox.items.clear()

it does not work

Please resolve my problem....
Thank you in advance...:)

Comment: I don't get what's the relation between the combobox not refresh and the code that are commented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to refresh the ComboBox should be OK, but no need to call cmbSn_no.Items.Clear() since cmbSn_no.DataSource = Nothing will remove all data from the ComboBox.

However, based on your code I assume that you declare your DataSet (ds) as form variable, thus when you want to fill in the **ds**, the old data (first 2 data - abcd123 bbbc123) is still there, and then run the Fill method will **add** those old data with **a whole set of new data - that are abcd123 bbbc123 cccc123**. To make sure, try to add this code **after da.Fill(ds, "Vendor_det")**:

```
MsgBox.Show(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
```

I think it will show 5, not 3. If that's the case, try to refresh the DataSet first before Fill, either by creating a new instance of DataSet, or delete the table.

Comment: Thanks a ton... u r write... i had declared dataset and data adapter as form variable..  I made them as private variable n now its working... Thank you...

Comment: Oh... i m so sorry...actually i want to comment the below lines n by mistake commented those:                                                                                                                                                                                        'cmbSn_no.DataSource = Nothing
            'cmbSn_no.Items.Clear()
            ' cmbSn_no.Refresh()